# CUDA: how to move array elements

Tags: cuda

I need to move each of the first k elements of a 1-D array by an offset,
wherethe offsets are monotonically increasing, i.e., if the offset for element i is offset1
then element i+1 has offset, offset2, that satisfies: offset2 >= offset1.

I wrote a kernel that is executed on each of the first k elements:

```
if (thread_id < k) {

  // compute offset

  if (offset) {
    int temp = a[thread_id];

    __synchthreads();

    a[thread_id + offset] = temp;
  }
}
```

However, when tested for k = 3, the offset are indeed monotonically increasing, namely
0, 1, 1.
Element 0 stays in its position as expected.
However, element 1 gets copied to not only element 2 (according to the offset for element 1), but also to element 3.

That is, it appears that thread 2 reads element 2 and stores it into its copy of temp only after thread 1 has completed the copy of element 1 to element 2.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: note that `__syncthreads()` only provides a barrier for the threads within a block.  So this method will break as soon as you go to more than one block in your grid.  Furthermore, if you are doing something silly, like launching a grid of threadblocks that each only have one thread, then the code will break everywhere.  Perhaps you should show a complete representation of your kernel along with the kernel invocation and computation of launch parameters.  You can simply edit your question with this info, don't try and stuff it in the comments.

Comment: Yes, I was incorrectly running 3 blocks of 1 thread each. It works fine with 1 block of 3 threads. However, this is limited to 1024 threads per block on a Tesla K20. How does one move more than 1024 elements? By moving one block of 1024 at a time, completing the work, before doing another block of 1024, and so on?

Comment: also, `__syncthreads()` inside a conditional block like that is not guaranteed to work.  Read [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions) about syncthreads in conditional code.  Concerning how to make it work across multiple thread blocks, you'll need a different algorithm that is parallelizable. I haven't thought about it extensively, but it seems to me if your output vector were different than your input vector, you'd avoid this hazard entirely.

Comment: How about __threadfence()? Can that be used in conditional code? Where are the differences between __syncthreads() and __threadfence() described?

Comment: @user1760748: `__threadfence()` is a *memory fence* and can be used conditionally, but it won't help here. You can see descriptions of all these functions in the [CUDA programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions).

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing generalizes to a scatter operation:

```
thread   0  1  2  3  4
in  =  { 1, 4, 3, 2, 5}
idx =  { 1, 2, 3, 4, 0}

out[idx] = in[i]
```

In general a scatter cannot be done in-place in parallel, because threads read from locations that other threads write. In our example, if thread 2 reads its input location *after* thread 1 writes its output location, we get incorrect results. This is a race condition, and requires either synchronization or out-of-place storage.

Since synchronization in this case for large arrays is global synchronization, which is not supported in the CUDA programming model, you must use out-of-place scatter.

In other words, you cannot do this:

```
temp = in[thread_idx]
global-sync
in[thread_idx + offset] = temp
```

You must do this:

```
out[i + offset] = in[thread_idx]
```

Where `out` does not point to the same memory as `in`.